# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with' (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, ado

I have a little bit of an odd issue.

When I run this SQL:

```
with ID_Table as ( 
    select row_number() over (order By SS_ID) As row_id, 
             ss_id 
      from slide_show ) 
     select t0.* 
       from ID_Table as t1 
inner Join slide_show as t0 on t1.ss_id = t0.ss_id 
    where t1.row_id between 0 and 1 
 order by t1.row_id asc;
```

in SQL Express, it runs and returns the first row as it should (similar to the Limit 0,1 in MySQL). However, when I run this in delphi via the TADOQuery object, I receive the error in the title. I am guessing the ADO object is doing something along the way but I don't understand what.

Note: This is the exact SQL I am passing into the ADO object.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT t0.*
FROM (SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY SS_ID) AS row_id, ss_id FROM slide_show) AS t1
INNER JOIN slide_show AS t0
ON t1.ss_id = t0.ss_id
WHERE t1.row_id BETWEEN 0 AND 1
ORDER BY t1.row_id ASC;
```

Comment: This is my thought too - the Delphi/ADO doesn't support WITH, which is just syntactic sugar for a derived table/inline view anways...

Comment: It occured to me after posting that this is in fact 2 statements trying to run. I wasn't aware you can subselect for a table though so this is just what I needed. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4):

The WITH keyword needs to be preceded by a semicolon when there are other statements before it in a batch (technically speaking, the preceding statement has to be terminated with ";", but just putting it before the WITH is a bit easier to maintain).

My guess is that ADO sets a connection variable or something similar, so the WITH is no longer first in the batch. Change it to ";WITH" and see if that works.

Comment: I've never had to prefix `WITH` with a semicolon - SQL Server or Oracle.

Comment: I just tested it to be sure I wasn't remembering incorrectly and received as error without the semicolon. For example, "SELECT 1 <newline> WITH My_CTE AS (SELECT 1 AS one)" fails, but I added the semicolon and it worked. This was in SQL 2008.

Comment: Implement best practise by ending all SQL statements with a semicolon and there's no issue.

Comment: It still becomes an issue if your code is being attached to other code over which you have limited or no control.

Comment: worked for me - python adodbapi + MS SQL Express 2005, Provider=sqloledb. So give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Which OLE DB provider are you specifying in your connection string? To be able to use the `WITH` (CTE) syntax you need to use the SQL Native Client provider e.g.

`Provider=SQLNCLI10.1`

rather than say the SQL Server OLE DB Provider e.g.

`Provider=SQLOLEDB.1`

Comment: Thats useful info, for situations where subselects won't work, this would be good.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
declare @a int
with ID_Table as ( 
    select row_number() over (order By SS_ID) As row_id, 
             ss_id 
      from slide_show ) 
     select t0.* 
       from ID_Table as t1 
inner Join slide_show as t0 on t1.ss_id = t0.ss_id 
    where t1.row_id between 0 and 1 
 order by t1.row_id asc;

//------------------------------
//with can not be the first row
```