# Reducing an extensive Query

Tags: sql, date

I am compiling historical data on work tickets from our db.  I am using the last day of the month for the past 12 months.  On that date I want to see how many tickets were open (datecreated before or equal to last day of month and dateclose after last day or null).  How many of those tickets had been open for more than 30 days as of the last day of the month, and how many tickets were closed during that month.

My query returns 4 values for each of the previous 12 months.  I developed a query where I gathered the data for one month at a time and then used Union to get the next month and so forth.

I am now attempting to develop a query which does not need a Union for each month of data collected.  Here is a sample month.

```
Select Convert(Varchar,
               DATEADD(day,
                       -1,
                       DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) - 12, 0)),
               101) as [ DateRun ],
       t1. [ data1 ],
       sum(t2. [ data2 ] + t3. [ data3 ]) as [ Total Open ],
       (t1. [ data1 ] + 0.0) /
       sum((t2. [ data2 ] + 0.0) + (t3. [ data3 ] + 0.0)) as [ Percent Aged Over 30 Days ]
  From (Select count(*) as [ data1 ]
          From (Select s.ticketnumber, s.datecreated, s.dateclosed
                  from mydb2 i
                 inner join mydb1 s
                    on i.ticketNumber = s.ticketNumber
                 Where datediff(dd,
                                s.dateCreated,
                                DATEADD(day,
                                        -1,
                                        DATEADD(mm,
                                                DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) - 12,
                                                0))) > '30'
                   AND (s.dateclosed is null OR
                        s.dateclosed >=
                        DATEADD(day,
                                -1,
                                DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) - 12, 0)))
                 Group by s.ticketNumber, s.datecreated, s.dateclosed) as tb1) as t1,
       (Select count(*) as [ data2 ]
          From (Select s.ticketnumber, s.datecreated, s.dateclosed
                  from mydb2 i
                 inner join mydb1 s
                    on i.ticketNumber = s.ticketNumber
                 Where s.datecreated <
                       DATEADD(day,
                               -1,
                               DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) - 12, 0))
                   AND (s.dateclosed is null OR
                       s.dateclosed >=
                       DATEADD(day,
                                -1,
                                DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) - 12, 0)))
                 Group by s.ticketNumber, s.datecreated, s.dateclosed) as tb2) as t2,
       (Select count(*) as [ data3 ]
          From (Select s.ticketnumber, s.datecreated, s.dateclosed
                  from mydb2 i
                 inner join mydb1 s
                    on i.ticketNumber = s.ticketNumber
                 Where s.dateclosed >
                       DATEADD(day,
                               -1,
                               DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) - 13, 1))
                   AND s.dateclosed <
                       DATEADD(day,
                               -1,
                               DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) - 12, 0))
                 Group by s.ticketNumber, s.datecreated, s.dateclosed) as tb3) as t3
 Group by t1. [ data1 ]
```

Through research I was able to get the past 12 months last day with the following code, but I have not been able to update the code above so that I don't need 12 Unions.

```
Select dateadd(month, 1 + datediff(month, 0, s.datecreated), -1) as [ Date Run ]
  from mydb1 s
 Where s.datecreated >
       DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) - 12, 0))
   and s.datecreated <
       DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
 Group by dateadd(month, 1 + datediff(month, 0, s.datecreated), -1)
 Order by 1
```

Comment: That indent structure makes me ill.

Comment: My apologies on the indenting (driving me crazy too).  The query is part of an MS Excel External Microsoft Query.  It did not copy and paste nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You might try generating the months using a CTE, use that as the basis for your query, then run the aggregates as subqueries.  In other words, something like this:

```
with Months( ClosingDate, n ) as
(
    select DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) as ClosingDate, 1 as n
    union all
    select DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, -1, DATEADD(dd, 1, ClosingDate))), n + 1
    from Months
    where n < 12
) 
select DATENAME(mm, m.ClosingDate) MonthLabel, DATEADD(dd, 1 - DATEPART(dd, m.ClosingDate), m.ClosingDate) OpeningDate, m.ClosingDate,
ISNULL((select COUNT(*)
    from mydb1 s
    where s.dateCreated < DATEADD(dd, -29, m.ClosingDate)
      and (s.dateClosed is null or s.dateClosed >= DATEADD(dd, 1, m.ClosingDate))
), 0) [Total Open 30+ Days]
from Months m
```

For clarity I included only one of the aggregates and omitted your joins and grouping.

Comment: This query is in MS Excel as an external Microsoft Query.  According to my research, using CTE doesn't work.  Do you know if that is an option in MS Excel?  I am able to get the data I want, I just want my query to be much better than it is.  I also felt this was something new programmers could learn from.

Comment: If you can create a view that uses the CTE, you could reference that from Microsoft Query.  Alternatively, you could eliminate Microsoft Query from the equation and connect to the database directly using a more feature-rich driver than ODBC.  Depending on what database and driver you use, [you may also need to put a semicolon before the start of the CTE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363704/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-with-sql).